# Attach progressbar in existing upload button

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have a browse button by which user can browse file upto 100 mb. But the problem is, it is uploading the attch file when user submitting the form. And it is not showing in anywhere that how much file uploaded. I want to show it with a progressbar.

U can visit my site http://historikindia.com/contact_us.php.

Please help me to do it. It is now sending attachment to my email. but i need to show user the progressbar otherwise they may think that it is not responding properly (for large file upload).

Comment: post your form please

Comment: I already attched the link of my form page. http://historikindia.com/contact_us.php.

Comment: Sure, but we can't see the code. That's the important thing in order to answer your question.

Comment: I have created two separated file. think it will help u.

Comment: 1. http://historikindia.com/form/ here u can look my form. 2. http://historikindia.com/form/frm_file/ here u can look all my from files.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code from ajax uploader which updated a status bar. You need to have an html5 progress bar in your html page for it to work.

```
function progressHandlingFunction(e){
    if(e.lengthComputable){
        $('progress').attr({value:e.loaded,max:e.total});
    }
}

$('#btnupload').click(function(){
                var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById('fileupload'));
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'upload.php', //server script to process data
                    type: 'POST',
                    xhr: function() {  // custom xhr
                        myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
                        if(myXhr.upload){ // check if upload property exists                               
                             myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false); // for handling the progress of the upload
                        }
                        return myXhr;
                    },
                    //Ajax events
                    beforeSend: function (e) { return true; },
                    success: function (json) { return true; },
                    error: function (json) { return false; },
                    // Form data
                    data: formData,
                    dataType: "json",
                    //Options to tell JQuery not to process data or worry about content-type
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false
                });
            });
```

html5 progress bar looks like this

```
 <progress value="1" max="100"></progress>
```

Comment: I added the code u said. I am a html coder I do not have much more sense about developing code. Please help me to do. I already put your code but not working just showing a bar.

Comment: it will be tough to me. Because i don't know the process. I can send the file if u need.

Comment: 1. http://historikindia.com/form/ here u can look my form. 2. http://historikindia.com/form/frm_file/ here u can look all my from files.

Comment: where is the `progressbar` where is the jscode nothing is there.

Comment: I removed the progressbar from here. It is a fresh copy. Previously i added the progressbar but that is not working so i decided to give u a fresh copy of my form.

Comment: I think you need to understand few things on how it works here. I don't write your code, you write your code, i can help you out to debug issues. I don't need fresh copies of your code. send me a link with the updated code so i can see what didn't work

Comment: In that case here is the link i put in my html http://www.historikindia.com/upload/contact_us.php